# Android ImageButton OnClick giving null pointer exception

Tags: android

Im calling a poup dialog from a menu option that says sign in with: then shows Twitter and Google logos as 2 imagebuttons.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            SummaryActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(SummaryActivity.this);
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.social_network_selection, null);
    alertadd.setView(view);
```

It inflates a view that contains the 2 imagebuttons.

when i add the code

```
    googleButton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.googleButton);
    twitterButton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.twitterButton);
```

All works fine but when i add the

```
googleButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

           Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
            "googleButton2 is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

It crashes with a null pointer. Not when i click the button but the second i call the AlertDialog that contains the ImageButtons

How do you add a listener to an imagebutton that is on an AlertDialog inflated View?

LOGCAT

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(SupportMenuInflater.java:259)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:191)
```

Comment: Please, post your logcat so we can check that. Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in these lines,

```
googleButton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.googleButton);
twitterButton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.twitterButton);
```

findViewById(int) method can not find the id in the context layout therefore it returns **null** value

**Solution**

You should have to use the findViewById method to find the view which was inflated by the layout context.

Here is the required solution for your task,

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                SummaryActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(SummaryActivity.this);
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.social_network_selection, null);
    alertadd.setView(view);
    googleButton2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.googleButton);
    twitterButton2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.twitterButton);

    googleButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

               Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                "googleButton2 is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call imagebutton with name of the View view and your onClick use getBaseContext()

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                SummaryActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(SummaryActivity.this);
        final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.social_network_selection, null);
    ImageButton googleButton2 = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.googleButton);
        ImageButton twitterButton2 = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.twitterButton);

    googleButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "googleButton2 is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
        alertadd.setView(view);
```